# Getting ERR! missing script: start on <npm start> command

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

When I run npm start, I get the dreaded "npm ERR! missing script: start"

---

Already tried changing the "start" line in the package.json in every way shown here and on Google going back a full year.

Also tried installing just about every stable node/npm stable release from the current to 12.x.  Deleted yarn just to be sure. Wnet back to current release.

Ran everything from npm init to npm create-react-app [project folder]
node_modules are there.

The script for run does show up in the package.json.

Deleted the project directory,deleted the repository and re-cloned the depository fresh.

---

OS: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon
Linux Mint 19.1 is based on Ubuntu 18.04.1
Vs Code 1.37.1 - all extensions disabled.

```
$ npm -v
6.9.0

$ whereis node
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/include/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz

$ which npm 
/usr/bin/npm

*******************************************
*package.json*:
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "name": "team-builder",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"

  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

- Note: I've tried every variant of the start script posted here in the past year.

debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /home/mark/.npmrc. (matches 
 userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
5 verbose stack     at run (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run- 
 script.js:155:19)
5 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run- 
 script.js:63:5
5 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read- 
  package-json/read-json.js:115:5
5 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read- 
 package-json/read-json.js:418:5
5 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ 
  (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read- 
 json.js:373:45)
5 verbose stack     at final 
  (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read - 
 json.js:416:3)
5 verbose stack     at then 
  (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read- 
  json.js:160:5)
5 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> 
  (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read- 
 json.js:3 32:20)
5 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback 
 (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful- 
 fs.js:90:16)
5 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] 
 (fs.js:237:13)
6 verbose cwd /home/mark/OneDrive/Repositories/team-builder
7 verbose Linux 4.15.0-58-generic
8 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
9 verbose node v10.16.3
10 verbose npm  v6.9.0
11 error missing script: start
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

---

I've tried just about everything.  I hope you all can help.
npm start won't run, so I'm basically coding blind - nothing to the monitor, no Chrome React devTools.

Answer (score 2):

Your scripts section looks off in your `package.json` perhaps you can change your start script to the following:

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

For full reference your scripts section should look similar to this, assuming you're trying to use `react` bootstrapped with the `create-react-app` cli:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Yeah, the way it was originally.  The last iteration was my last hope for the script.  I changed it back just now, and nope... no cigar.  I've literally tried every script variant here and on Google - that was my first thought. Still, I really appreciate you reaching out.  That helps - it least I know I'm not suffering silently with this dang error!

Comment: can you post just your package.json file as you have it currently as well as your entire error stack trace?

Comment: Ok, I posted the info up.  I included the debug log - I stll had it up.  Let me know if there's anything alse you need.  Thanks.

Comment: remove this line in your package.json: `main": "index.js",` then try rerunning. Also, what version of create-react-app did you use?

Comment: Thanks, Nathan.  I tried taking that line out as well, unfortunately.  Sorry, I thought I'd posted the whole package.json .  I'm not on that laptop now, but I'm running create-react-app v 3.1.1. I'll post the full package.json later. In the mean time, I bought an older laptop and pushed it into  service. Seems to be running fine, but a little slowly.  Worst case, I'm out $35. I'm getting  a new box next week some time, so the urgency has ratcheted down a whole lot.

Comment: ok hopefully it all works out! I would recommend updating create-react-app and starting a fresh project just to see if the problem persists. If not then you can port over the code and you know there was an issue with initialization from CRA

Comment: Took your advice there, and was finally coding again.  I really appreciate your help.

Lesson learned?  I took for granted that the OS was bullet-proof.  Shouldn't have ruled it out -  there are no absolutes in debugging.